# jboss forge cannot setup plugins

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss, jboss-forge

I wanna create a jboss forge plugin but I have massive problems running forge...

When I start forge inside Eclipse or from command prompt it takes quite a long time and then I always get this huge Exception. (see bottom)

Then when I create my plugin project and wanna setup the plugins API. Forge freezes for about 1 minute and then gives me this Exception

```
Wrote <pathtoworkspace>/pluginforge/pom.xml
***ERROR*** Exception encountered: null (type "set VERBOSE true" to enable stack traces)
```

After that my pom.xml is broken with an dependency regarding jboss-javaee-6.0

reinstalling jboss developer tools didn't help either. cmd prompt and eclipse integration producing the same issues..
I have no idea what to do...already wasting hours on this... Hopefully someone can help
.

Startup-Exception:

```
Error during PostStartup event
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.contains(String.java:2076)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.containsCoordinates(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.importDependencyManagement(DefaultModelBuilder.java:948)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:403)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:374)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:232)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:102)
    at org.jboss.forge.maven.facets.MavenCoreFacetImpl.getPartialProjectBuildingResult(MavenCoreFacetImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.forge.maven.facets.MavenCoreFacetImpl.resolveProperties(MavenCoreFacetImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.forge.maven.facets.MavenDependencyFacet.resolveProperties(MavenDependencyFacet.java:393)
    at org.jboss.forge.maven.facets.MavenDependencyFacet.hasEffectiveDependency(MavenDependencyFacet.java:171)
    at org.jboss.forge.spec.javaee.BaseJavaEEFacet.isInstalled(BaseJavaEEFacet.java:64)
    at org.jboss.forge.spec.javaee.cdi.CDIFacetImpl.isInstalled(CDIFacetImpl.java:51)
    at org.jboss.forge.project.BaseProject.registerFacet(BaseProject.java:153)
    at org.jboss.forge.project.services.ProjectFactory.registerSingleFacet(ProjectFactory.java:208)
    at org.jboss.forge.project.services.ProjectFactory.registerSingleFacet(ProjectFactory.java:186)
    at org.jboss.forge.project.services.ProjectFactory.registerFacets(ProjectFactory.java:178)
    at org.jboss.forge.project.services.ProjectFactory.findProjectRecursively(ProjectFactory.java:117)
    at org.jboss.forge.shell.project.ProjectInitializer.doInit(ProjectInitializer.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:305)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:163)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:299)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:188)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:59)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:198)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:282)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:265)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:234)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.notifyObservers(BeanManagerImpl.java:635)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:628)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:75)
    at org.jboss.forge.shell.project.ProjectInitializer.postStartupTrigger(ProjectInitializer.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:305)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:163)
```

Comment: strange... I opened a different workspace and used forge in there. Same errors. Then I switched back to my old workspace and now it works like a charm... I don't know what was wrong .. but I am happy it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

A very late answer, but I hope this helps anyone else who has run into this. This looks like you had problems with Maven dependency resolution. Either it failed, or it was sloe, or the dependencies were being downloaded but timed out.

When you change the project context in Forge, i.e. you `cd` into a project directory, or when you run a command that modifies the project's dependency hierarchy, Forge will attempt a partial or a full Maven build. One of the aspects of this build is a dependency resolution process that attempts to ensure that any dependencies especially those required for activating Forge facets are available in your local Maven repository.

With Forge 1.4.0+ (especially the upcoming 1.4.1) release, the shell should output any warnings in this area, should there be a failure in dependency resolution at any point.

As a tip, it would be better to operate a Maven repository manager like Nexus or Artifactory that would heavily reduce the possibility of slow artifact downloads or timeouts.